# Execute on Raspberry Pi using SSH a command that let run a .py script on another Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, networking, ssh, raspberry-pi

I am trying to let my Raspberry Pi run a script that triggers a SSH command to another Raspberry Pi on my LAN network that runs another script. How do I go about connecting them?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question well, you want to run a script remotely?

Using ssh, you can just pass as extra argument the command you want to execute, for example on pi1:

```
ssh user@pi2 python my_script.py
```

Or if you want to do that in python too:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("ssh user@pi2 python my_script.py", shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, however i am getting an error still. See my code down below

Answer (score 0):

## On the Pi you want to run the remote script on

First, you need to enable passwordless login on the you want to connect with. Log in to it, and run in Terminal

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id pi@raspberrypi
```

You'll need to enter your local pi password to allow your local Pi to access the remote one

## On the other Pi

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["ssh","USER@HOSTNAME","./PATH"])
```

- USER is your username on the remote Pi.
- HOSTNAME is the IP address (get this by running `hostname -I` on the remote Pi.)
- PATH is the path to the script that you want to run on the remote Pi.